# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x(x-t)\sin t^2\ dt}{x\sin^3x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

How to integrate this?

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^x(x-t)\sin t^2\ dt}{x\sin^3x}.$$

I've had difficulty in using L'Hopital rule. At the same time failed to really understand how to differentiate or evaluate the limit of the $x\sin^3x$ and $\int_0^x(x-t)\sin t^2\ dt$

Would like to appreciate your help

Comment: l'Hospital....?

Comment: I've already did that  integrated it three times. but i still kept getting zero. And it was getting more complicated for the denominator which kind of contradicts the use of L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: How would it contradict the use of l'Hopital?

Comment: I've been taught that when using L'Hopital rule, the differentiated should not make the whole thing complicated. However, should I just proceed in still doing L'Hopital rule and differentiate it the fourth time? A friend and I have differentiated xsin^3x but kept getting 0 to no avail.

Comment: @sallyg Is  it ok now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use repeatedly $\sin u=u\,{\rm sinc}(u)$, whereby $\lim_{u\to0}{\rm sinc}(u)={\rm sinc}(0)=1$. We have
$$\int_0^x (x-t)\sin(t^2)\>dt=x^4\int_0^1(1-\tau)\,\tau^2{\rm sinc}(x^2\tau^2)\>d\tau$$
and $$\>x\sin^3 x=x^4\>{\rm sinc}^3(x)\ ,$$ so that
$${\int_0^x (x-t)\sin(t^2)\>dt \over x\sin^3 x}={\int_0^1(1-\tau)\,\tau^2\bigl(1+r(x,\tau)\bigr)\>d\tau\over 1+\bar r(x)}\ ,$$
whereby $\lim_{x\to0}r(x,\tau)=0$ uniformly in $\tau$, and $\lim_{x\to0}\bar r(x)=0$ as well. It follows that the limit in question is
$$\int_0^1(1-\tau)\,\tau^2\>d\tau={1\over12}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot. i forgot the Lemma Rule

Answer (score 2):

Write the numerator as
$$
f(x)=x\int_0^x\sin t^2\,dt-\int_0^x t\sin t^2\,dt
$$
Then the FTC and the product rule tell you that
$$
f'(x)=\int_0^x\sin t^2\,dt+x\sin x^2-x\sin x^2=\int_0^x\sin t^2\,dt
$$
Therefore
$$
f''(x)=\sin x^2
$$
Thus, applying l'Hôpital twice,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^4}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{4x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{12x^2}=\frac{1}{12}
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x\sin^3x}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^4}\frac{x^3}{\sin^3x}=\frac{1}{12}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

$f(x)=x\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt-\int_0^xt\sin(t^2)dt$

and

$g(x)=x\sin^3(x)$

$g(x)$ is equivalent to $h(x)=x^4$ and we will have the same limit if we replace

$g(x)$by $h(x)$.

we will compute

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$

and use

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

$f'(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt+x\sin(x^2)-x\sin(x^2)=x\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt $

thus your limit is $\color{red}{\frac{1}{12}}$ after a second l' Hopital rule.

Comment: I don't see it clearly: first, that "$\;g(x)\;$ is equivalent..." part is not clear at all: why is it true? You can say that $\;|\sin x|<x\;$ for small values (in abs. val.) of $\;x\;$ , yet that the values of both expressions in the limits, "when doing l'Hospital", will be the same is, I believe, something that must be proved. Also, how did you get the equality $$\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt+x\sin(x^2)-x\sin(x^2)=x\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt\;\;?$$ Where does the $\;x\;$ factor in the rightmost side come from?

Comment: @Ab No, it isn't still clear: in the middle expression of $\;f'(x)\;$ , the second and third summand cancel with each other, and you're then left only with the integral $\;\int_0^x \sin t^2\,dt\;$ . Why do you multiply this by $\;x\;$ on the right side?

Comment: Your $f'(x)$ has a factor of $x$ too much. It's probably just a typo, since the end result is correct.

Comment: The problem with that factor $\;x\;$ there is that it has a very big importance for the limit, specially because of the claim that the denominator "is like $\;x^4\;$ in the limit", which seems to be a rather important thing to state without a proof or, at least, without a hint why it works that way *in this case*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}(x - t)\sin t^{2}\,dt$$ then it can be easily proved (using integration by parts) that $$f''(x) = \sin x^{2}, f(0) = f'(0) = 0$$ and therefore we can use L'Hospital's Rule twice to get the answer easily.

We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x\sin^{3}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^{4}}\cdot\frac{x^{3}}{\sin^{3}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{4x^{3}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f''(x)}{12x^{2}}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{12}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x^{2}}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{12}
\end{align}

---

More generally if $$F(x) = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!}\int_{a}^{x}(x - t)^{n - 1}f(t)\,dt$$ then $$F^{(n)}(x) = f(x), F(a) = F'(a) = F''(a) = F^{(n - 1)}(a) = 0$$ Further note that it is **never a good idea to jump to L'Hospital Rule directly** (unless the problem is too simple) and it is *better to transform the expression into a form where application of L'Hospital's Rule is easy*. Thus in the solution provided above we have effectively replaced the expression $x\sin^{3}x$ in denominator with $x^{4}$ and then applied L'Hospital's Rule. This considerably simplifies the process of L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 0):

An idea with Taylor expansions:

$$(x-t)\sin t^2=(x-t)\left(t^2-\frac{t^6}6+\ldots\right)=xt^2-\frac{xt^6}6-t^3+\frac{t^7}6+\ldots\implies$$

$$\int_0^x(x-t)\sin t^2\,dt=\left.\left(\frac x3t^3-\frac14t^4+\ldots\right)\right|_0^x=\frac{x^4}3-\frac{x^4}4+\ldots=\frac{x^4}{12}+\ldots$$

Observe that the $\;\ldots\;$ above is an expression which, upon substituting $\;t\to x\;$, has an exponent higher than $\;4\;$ . Because of the following this won't contribute anything in the limit.

We also have

$$x\sin^3x=x\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+\ldots\right)^3=x(x^3+\ldots)=x^4+\ldots$$

Thus our limit is

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{x^4}{12}}{x^4}=\frac1{12}$$

Comment: No, in your $f(t)$ there is an $(x-t)\sin(t^2)$.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\int_0^x xdt$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam $2x$

Comment: And the derivative of $\int_0^x x\sin(t^2)dt$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I just cannot understand your first comment. I've no idea what that "no" means, towards what it is directed or what. For the second one you already were answered, but again: $\;\int_0^x x\,dt=x\int_0^x dt=x\cdot x=x^2\implies\frac d{dx}\left(\int_0^x x\,dt\right)=2x \;$

Comment: For your last comment above: $${}$$$$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_0^x x\sin t^2\,dt\right)=\frac d{dx}\left(x\int_0^x\sin t^2\,dt\right)=\int_0^x \sin t^2\,dt+x\sin x^2+C$$

Comment: FTC works if there is no $x$ under $\int$ symbol.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Says who? Why should that be so? The integrand function is a continuous function **of** $\;t\;$ , which is what we care about, as variable, in an integral like the one we have here $\;\int ...dt\;$ . If we were given that $\;x\;$ is a function of $\;t\;$ then that'd be *way another issue* . But  as far as I can see I can regard it as *constant* wrt $\;t\;$ ...

Comment: In your solution, one must use $f(x,t)$ instead of $f(t)$. The FTC doesn't work in the first case.

Comment: You have the wrong $F'$ (and hence a wrong end result). $F'(x) = \int_0^x \sin (t^2)\,dt$.

Comment: @DanielFischer $F$ is a product of $x$which we can write outside $\int$ and    a second term whose derivative is obtained by FTC.

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I don't think $\;F'\;$*has* to be what you say, though I certainly missed the fact that $\;x\;$ is, a constant wrt $\;t\;$ , not to be taken into consideration for the primitive (funny: exactly what I sadi to Abdallah before). I shall edit and take your idea if possible.

Comment: I thought you meant $F(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)\sin (t^2)\,dt + C$ (taking $C = 0$ is the most natural thing, but what constant you choose doesn't matter). If you meant something else, I have no idea what.

Comment: In fact I tried to choose the $\;F\;$ in FTC for which $\;\int_a^b g(t)dt= G(b)-G(a)\;$  (well, so $\;F=G\;$ ), so no need of constant there. Yet I am checking now your idea, defining only $\;F\;$ to be the primitive of $\;\sin t^2\;$, since $\;\int t\sin t^2\,dt=-\frac12\cos t^2\;$ , but then I get the limit doesn't exist finitely...I must chech this more thoroughly.

Comment: Using the Taylor expansion is much easier than mucking about with L'Hospital anyway here.

Comment: @DanielFischer It seems so...I get $\;\frac7{12}\;$ . Shall recheck later. Surprisingly, WA agrees with me.

Comment: That is indeed surprising. For it is $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}$ and not $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: No, not in that stage: the whole limit *after* taking out the integral....something must be wrong there but I won't check it anymore. I took your idea and came up with an approach via Taylor. Thanks.